# Is it possible to use the batch API with transactions?

Tags: 7, database, batch-operations

I'm using the batch api for reading large csv files and storing some information in my database. If something fails during the batch run I want all the processed information to be gone, I would like to use drupals [transactions](https://drupal.org/node/355875) for this, but I don't know if this is supported.

If this is not supported is there any known workaround for this?

Comment: *[You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* - is there an actual problem with your imports you want to solve with transactions?

Comment: Yes the problem is that a batch run that encouters an error leaves my import in an unknown state. I would like to avoid that state by executing a db->rollback (or something smiliar) on error.

Comment: A workaround is to use standalone file w/ a `drush scr`.  This will get around execution time problems.

Comment: That may be a workaround, but not for my scenario - I can't give users of my site shell access :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. 
Batch API divides task into separate steps, each in it's own PHP call. In pure PHP (for simplicity) you use transactions [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2708247/2389310):

```
try {
    // First of all, let's begin a transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $db->query('first query');
    $db->query('second query');
    $db->query('third query');

    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $db->rollback();
}
```

To split it into multiple calls, you would need to store PDO object and pass it between calls, but [PDO objects cannot be serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8700726/2389310).

**Workaround** would be to import to a temporary table, and when (if) it was successful, use one more batch api step to move data from temporary one to real destination. And that one last move you can do in one step, so you can wrap it with transaction.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought, but I wanted to make sure. Thanks for your answer. Regarding the temporary table,  Maybe I will do that, but the simplest solution I can think of is if I have an error during the batch run to write some error-info into `$context['results']` and check that in my finished-callback function and delete all rows that were inserted if I had an error.

Comment: @walfish Well, your way has some serious issues - it assumes that failure in import will not kill the batch api ability to delete imported data, it forces you to put site in maintenance mode for the whole long time of your import, or to expose data you might need to have deleted as if they never existed, and it requires a reliable method of marking data that came from import of a certain ID.

Comment: I do keep meta-information of the import in a table, such as ID, user etc. and also a status column to prevent (as you already described) displaying wrong/unfinished import information. an interesting thread about handling an error state inside batch api. although it'is from 2007 I think it is still relevant: https://drupal.org/node/175185